# How accurate is an Amazon Kinesis record's ApproximateArrivalTimestamp?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-sdk, aws-cli, amazon-kinesis

Last year AWS [announced](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/09/amazon-kinesis-server-side-timestamp/) a server-side timestamp for Kinesis records.

How accurate is this timestamp?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Each Amazon Kinesis record includes a value, ApproximateArrivalTimestamp, that is set when an Amazon Kinesis stream successfully receives and stores a record. This is commonly referred to as a server-side timestamp, whereas a client-side timestamp is set when a data producer creates or sends the record to a stream. The timestamp has millisecond precision. **There are no guarantees about the timestamp accuracy**, or that the timestamp is always increasing. For example, records in a shard or across a stream might have timestamps that are out of order.

From [GetRecords](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetRecords.html), emphasis mine.